# Issues with extracting variables from NetCDF file in python

Tags: python, matlab, netcdf

I'm new to python, and have some experience with matlab. I am not getting the correct values for outgoing longwave radiation from the netCDF file and I have tried the scipy.io.netcdf module and the Scientific.IO.NetCDF module.

```
import Scientific.IO.NetCDF as S
fileobj = S.NetCDFFile('filename.nc', mode='r')
data = fileobj.variables['var'].getValue()  # I tried both with and w/o the .getValue()
print data[0:10,43,80] #first ten points in time at a specific lat/lon
[ -5124  -5335  -5121  -5499  -5508  -8930 -10111  -9435  -8534  -8487]
```

My code using scipy.io.netcdf was the same except I didn't use the .getValue(). I then tried this exercise in matlab

```
data = ncread('filename.nc','var');
data[80,43,1:10] %note matlab orders the data lon, lat, time
ans(:,:,1) =

  275.0400


ans(:,:,2) =

  279.0800


ans(:,:,3) =

  279.6800


ans(:,:,4) =

  277.8700


ans(:,:,5) =

  275.5900


ans(:,:,6) =

  241.4700


ans(:,:,7) =

  223.1900


ans(:,:,8) =

  235.5700


ans(:,:,9) =

  239.8200


ans(:,:,10) =

  249.5400
```

I know that the values produced from matlab are correct. This variable should be in a range of 80-330 (watts per square meter). Any ideas on what's going on with python?
thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be `print data[0:10,42,79]` instead? Python indexes from 0, Matlab from 1.

Comment: Ah, yes. You're right. However, the values are still in the -10,000 range while they should be in the 80-330 range. I did a little more work today and found that if I use MATLAB's 'low level' netcdf package, just called netcdf.getVar , then I get the same answer as python.

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax:

```
from scipy.io.netcdf import netcdf_file as Dataset

ncfile = Dataset('filename.nc','r')
data = ncfile.variables['var'][:,:,:]
```